# Creation of object which doesn't have model, while creation need to create several entries in other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In application user can enter new **post** which contain *title*, *content* of the post and *category* of post. So creating new post will be through some simple html form with few fields. Now i don't know where to put logic for creating new post for following reasons:

Post(or posts collection) is object which is constructed from different tables, for example.

```
@posts = User.joins(entries: [{storage: :vote}, :category]) 
             .where("votes.count > ?", 0)
             .select("users.username AS username,
                      storages.id AS storage_id,
                      storages.title AS title, 
                      storages.content AS content, 
                      votes.count AS votes, 
                      categories.category_name AS category_name")
             .order("votes.count DESC")
```

So when user create **new post** application must create new entries in different tables:

1.Create new entry in **entries** table. `(id, user_id, category_id)`
2. Create new entry in **storages** table.`(id, title, content, entry_id)` 
3. Create new entry in **vote** table.`(id, count, storage_id)`

In situation where **post** is model i can use something like `resources: posts` then in posts controller through `new` and `create` i can create new post, **but what in situation like this where i don't need posts controller nor post model?** So, question is: which place is more appropriate to put logic for creating new post? **Q1**

My solution is to craete Storages controller with `resource: storages, :only => [:new, :create]` then through new and create of this controller to populate different tables in db? I'm forcing here `only` because i dont see any point of other CRUD actions here(like showing all or one storage), because i will not use storages individually but in conjunction with other tables. So from views/storages through new.html.erb and create.html.erb i can construct new **post**? **Q2**

Another solution is to create Post controller which doesn't have "corresponding" post model as i stated before. Here i'm guessing i can't use restful routes(CRUD) because there is not `:id` of post? I only can make manually non-restful routes like:
`post 'posts/create/:title/:content/:category' => 'posts#create', :as => 'create_post'`  then from `params[:title]`, `params[:content]` and `params[:category]` to populate other tables. **Q3**

Im new to rails so dont yell please :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sound like a call for nested forms, its covered in a screen cast 
[here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

You use the resources of the top model, in this case Entry.
and drill down to the 3rd model.

Simple sample of what to do is bellow.
Model should look like so,

entry.rb

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :storages, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :storages, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

storage.rb

```
class Storage < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :entry
  has_many :votes, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :votes, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

vote.rb

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :storage
end
```

and the form should look like so, in simple_form style

```
<%= simple_form_for @entry do |f| %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :storages do |storage_fields| %>
    <%= storage_fields_for :votes do |vote_fields| %>

    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and if you have all the models set up, you shouldn't have to do anything to the controller.

This approach is also nice because you can add multiple storages and votes ajax style(without reloading the page) if needed, which is always nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a form class instead of nested attributes any day, see http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ for an example of this pattern (Chapter "3. Extract Form Objects")

I've used the pattern often enough to gemify it https://github.com/bbozo/simple_form_class and it's used roughly in this way: https://gist.github.com/bbozo/5036937, if you're interested to use it I'll push some docs

EDIT: reason why I tend to go the form class route most of the time is because nested attributes never failed to bite me in the end, either because strong parameter handling got cumbersome, or validators get too complicated (if persisted? else ...), or persistence logic needs to be extended to support some little knack that resolves into callback hell or recursive saves in the model (before/after save spaghetti troubles)